# How to import the Python requests module in a script executed from PHP

Tags: python, php, python-requests, shell-exec

I have a PHP code:

```
<?PHP
echo shell_exec("python test.py '100'");
?>
```

that executes a Python script:

```py
import sys
input=sys.argv[1]
print(input)
```

That works totally fine.

But if I try to import requests:

```py
import sys 
import requests
input=sys.argv[1]
print(input)
```

It simply stops working. No output at all.

Requests is installed and from the bash my script works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: FYI: You should use the absolute path to the binary with the `requests` module installed, ie: `/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/test.py '100'`. Try adding [`2>&1`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to the end of the command as suggested in the doc comments

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php
          $command = escapeshellcmd ("./working.py") ;
          $output = shell_exec ($command) ;
          echo "<p>$output</p>" ;
?>
```

working.py

```
print("runned!")
```